# Rails/ActiveRecord: Can I perform this query without passing the SQL string to #order?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models `Issue` and `Label`. They have a many to many relationship.

I have a method that returns the ten labels that point to the most issues.

```
class Label < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags
  has_many :issues, through: :tags

    def self.top
        Label.joins(:issues)
        .group(:name)
        .order('count_id desc')
        .count(:id)
        .take(10)
    end
end
```

It does exactly what I expect it to but I want to know if it's possible to compose the query without the SQL string.

`order('count_id DESC')` is confusing me. Where does `count_id` come from? There isn’t a column named `count_id`.

```
Label.joins(:issues).group(:name).column_names
#=> ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

I’ve found some SQL examples [here](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by).  I think it’s basically the same as `ORDER BY COUNT(Id)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), Country
FROM Customer
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC
```

Is it possible to perform the same query without passing in the SQL string? Can it be done with the ActiveRecord querying interface alone?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your query log, you'll see something like:

```
select count(labels.id) as count_id ...
```

The combination of your `group` call (with any argument) and the `count(:id)` call gets ActiveRecord to add the `count_id` column alias to the query. I don't think this is documented or specified anywhere (at least that I can find) but you can see it happen if you're brave enough to walk through the Active Record source.

In general, if you add a GROUP BY and then `count(:x)`, Active Record will add a `count_x` alias. There's no column for this so you can't say `order(:count_id)`, `order(count_id: :desc)`, or any of the other common non-String alternatives. AFAIK, you have to use a string but you can wrap it in an `Arel.sql` to prevent future deprecation issues:

```
Label.joins(:issues)
     .group(:name)
     .order(Arel.sql('count_id desc'))
     .count(:id)
     .take(10)
```

There's no guarantee about this so if you use it, you should include something in your test suite to catch any problems if the behavior changes in the future.